# Discord Bot sending random message

Tags: javascript, random, discord, bots

I want the the discord bot to pick a random message out of several options. And it kinda works: The bot picks a random message, but only by restarting the bot.
Code:

```
const percent = ["0-10%" , "10-20%" , "20-30%" , "30-40%" , "40-50%" , "50-60%" , "60-70%" , "70-80%" , "80-90%" , "90-100%"]
const result = Math.floor(Math.random() * percent.length);

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content.startsWith('.percent')){ var mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();
         const wvg = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setColor('#ff4da6')
           .addFields(
            { name: message.mentions.members.first().user.username 
            , value: "percent:" } ,
            { name: percent[result]
                , value: "text" }
           )
           
           .setTimestamp()
           .setFooter(message.author.username);

        message.channel.send(wvg)
        console.log(message.member.user.tag +' executed command .percent')
    }
})
```

Would be nice if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself. I just put the two consts under the if.